# PHP - readfile() failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php

I have the following script:
/var/www/vhosts/default/download/index.php

I am using readfile(); to serve files:

```
$path = '/data/'. $arr["$product"] .'';
readfile($path);
```

But The following error is generated:

> [error] [client xx] PHP Warning:  readfile(/data/xxx.iso): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/default/download/index.php on line 33, referer: http://zxc.com/

I thought it is caused by permissions, therefor I gave 777 to the /data directory and 777 to the files in /data, but didn't solve the problem. Then I changed the owner of the directory + files to apache, but also didn't solve it.

What else could be the problem? Also tried to solve it with open_basedir. but no success.

Comment: Remove the first slash `/`for a relative path? Or is data really a top level directory?

Comment: Oh sorry, the direct folder is: /data/ (it is on a different partition)

Comment: Does the file actually exist? (Check with [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-exists.php))

Comment: Yes, the file does exist. I copied the filename from the error log and checked via SSH. The file does exist.

Comment: Is the file in /var/www/vhosts/default/download/data/yourfile ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. It seems SELinux was enabled. Disabled SELinux and it is working now.

Comment: https://stopdisablingselinux.com/ If the issue is with SELinux you should fix the related permissions issue.